# Why in this C program If condition is true?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, precision

I am comparing two equal values but why a < 0.7 is true, one more thing i wanted to check the datatype of 0.7 but I don't know how to do this.

```
void main(){
  float a = 0.7;
    if(a < 0.7){
       printf("c");
    }else{
       printf("c++");
    }
}
```

Output: c

one more example:

```
int a = 10;

if(a > 10){
 printf("if block");
}else{
 printf("else block");
}
```

Output: else block

Comment: compare to `0.7f`, `0.7` is double

Comment: single precision floating point representation of `0.7` is `0.699999988`

Comment: can i check 0.7 is double in c program. if yes how

Comment: There is compile time error,include semicolon after printf('c++')

Comment: @pergy why 0.7 is double? 
is it by default every number in c get double datatype.

Comment: c supports double? I dont think we can make a double variable in c.

Comment: @SagarBalyan how so? Are you sure you are talking about C and not about some my-awesome-hardware subset of C?

Comment: @SagarBalyan your teacher is... scary?! `void` as a datatype, only 4 primitives, ... thats all so messed up. However, 4 primitives is not completely wrong... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types *Basic types* section

Comment: @grek40 can u explain other example in my question

Comment: @jazz_razor Is there really a need to explain the second example? `10` is in memory without any rounding errors and 10 is not  greater than 10

Comment: @grek40 So shed me some light. How many data types are there in c? and which one are the primitive ones?

Comment: @grek40 yeah... oh sorry you are correct...

Comment: @jazz_razor yes, afaik every literal with decimal point get `double` type unless adding `f` postfix

Comment: more precisely, from the standard:
"An unsuffixed floating constant has type double. If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has
type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double."
[See point 6.4.4.2 / 4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

Comment: @pergy Detail; in C, `0.7` is a _constant_.  C has 2 _literals_: _string literal_ and _compound literal_.  `0.7` is neither of those 2 literals.

Comment: @chux yes, thx for clarification

Comment: @jazz_razor The quickest way to let you know something is amiss is to turn on all compiler warnings.  This saves you time.  `float a = 0.7f;` may generate "warning: conversion to 'float' alters 'double' constant value [-Wfloat-conversion]" letting you know _something_ is going on.  `float a = 0.7f;` would fix that warning.  Now `0.7f` and `0.7` at least look different in code - giving you a hint there may be an important difference.

Comment: @jazz_razor To check the data type, research `_Generic`